# Why does this array.filter always return nothing?

Tags: javascript, filter

Why does this filter never return any objects?

```
NewHashMap.prototype.remove = function (keys, obj) {
    // snip
    var myEntries = this.entries;
    var filteredEntries = myEntries.filter(
        function(entry){
            //me.isContainedBy(entry, keys) &&
            //entry.obj === obj
            true;
        });
    console.debug("entries ",  myEntries.length);
    console.debug("filtered ", filteredEntries.length);
    // snip
}
```

A bit further I use it in a different context and it works.
You also see that I commented out my actual filter requirements and replaced them by a plain True. Same thing.

I'm guessing it's a context issue, but I don't see where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `true` does nothing unless you `return` it from the anonymous function:

```
var filteredEntries = myEntries.filter(
    function(entry){
        //me.isContainedBy(entry, keys) &&
        //entry.obj === obj
        return true;
});
```

Or with your actual filter code:

```
var filteredEntries = myEntries.filter(
    function(entry){
        return me.isContainedBy(entry, keys) && entry.obj === obj
});
```

Comment: DOH! Notepad++ must have been laughing in my face for about an hour now :P

Answer (score 3):

You need to `return` a boolean value from the callback function:

```
var filteredEntries = myEntries.filter(
        function(entry){
            //me.isContainedBy(entry, keys) &&
            //entry.obj === obj
            return true;
        });
```